# StrongLoop Fails to Deploy: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

Strongloop is failing to deploy to a Ubuntu Digital Ocean instance.

After executing the commands here:

http://strong-pm.io/prod/

On the remote box:

```
npm install -g strong-pm
sudo /sbin/initctl start strong-pm
```

On local machine where the app is built:

```
slc build
slc deploy http://--->hostIPaddress
```

I get this error

```
Error connecting to server: { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
Failed to deploy `../placesAPI-1.0.0.tgz` as `placesAPI` to `http://hostIPaddress/` via `http://hostIPaddress/`
```

Comment: Hmm... could be a number of things. The PM communicates on port 8701 by default, perhaps that is not open on your DO box? You may also want to check out the [gitter chat channel](https://gitter.im/strongloop/chat), or even the [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/strongloop). (Or you could try opening a support ticket using: support@strongloop.com)

Comment: Thanks-- you were right.  I had the port it was trying to run on blocked by a firewall.   I opened the port and it seems to deploy now.   It you make it the answer I will mark it correct and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the StrongLoop process manager runs on **port 8701** by default. So the first step is to check that port to see if it's blocked by the host system. If it's not blocked, I would ensure that the process manager is actively running (you can use `slc ctl status` to check that).